# Normalization of column values + Creating new column with normalized values

Tags: r

I'm trying to learn how to normalize values in a given column in a dataset/frame in R and input those normalized values in a newly created column.

I was able to find two codes -one that helped me normalize the values and one that helped me create a column.

However, what I have been unable to do is input the normalized values in the newly created column.

I'm playing with dataset Indometh (inbuilt in R). I wanted to create a column ConcNorm that would have normalized values (between 0 and 1) of Conc column already existing in Indometh.

Could someone help with get my head around this?

```
Indometh["Concnorm"] <- NA

normalize <- function(Indometh) { 
    Indometh <- sweep(Indometh, 2, apply(Indometh, 2, min)) 
    sweep(Indometh, 2, apply(Indometh, 2, max), "/") 
}
```

UPDATE:`myNorm = function (x) {(x- min(Indometh$conc)) / (max(Indometh$conc)-min(Indometh$conc))}
MyNorm(0.05)
myNorm(2.7)`

Another code i came up with looked like:

The above is what i came up with researching online however this isnt working/serving the purpose.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I missing something?

```
df <- Indometh
df$scaledConc <- with(df, (conc - min(conc))/diff(range(conc)))
range(df$scaledConc)
# [1] 0 1
```

Generally, it's a bad idea to mess with the built-in datasets. That's why I copied first to `df`.

Comment: so i did some more reading that helped me understand your code much better. I used it and it seemed to have worked well. Thanks again.

Comment: Since you're new to SO, [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) explains what to do when someone answers your question. The convention is to wait 24 hrs before accepting an answer, in case someone else comes along with a better one.

Answer (score 0):

This function receives the data.frame object and the names of the original and new column:

```
  normalize.col = function(data, orig.col, new.col) {

   val.range = range(data[, orig.col])
   data[, new.col] = (data[, orig.col] - val.range[1])/(val.range[2] - val.range[1])

   data
}
```

Example (you can pass more than one column too):

```
Indometh_norm = normalize.col(Indometh, 'conc', 'normConc')
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. But what is val.range and what does it do here? Would this normalize between 0 and 1 ? Also, your example doesnt match the generic code you provided. Is the code i provided under "Update" section of my post any good? could you expand on that instead?

Comment: val.range is the minimum/maximum value, yes this normalizes to 0 and 1. What do you mean by doesn't match? It normalizes and add a new column.

Comment: Thanks again. I see in your example another normalized column was added. But the code what you provided and the code mentioned in the example don't look alike is what i was referring to. Sorry -I'm a newbie to R so still trying to understand some of these technicalities.